# NET.MAUI: Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK nuget is blocked by project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, maui

*I have looked at all the suggested post answers here, unfortunately they refer to NETCore up to 3.1. As I am using NET 7 in my MAUI project, I don't think I should use the suggested solutions. Therefore I decided to ask a new question here.*

Due to an error in WebView2.Control, I need to update Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK to a higher version. When I go into Nuget Management in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.5.3), I cannot install or uninstall this Nuget to a higher version. Everything is grey and the message "Blocked by project" appears.

By the way, there are a few more Nuget that have the same problem, here are just a few:

- Nuget Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

With the rest of the nuggets, I can both install to any version and uninstall.

Does anyone know this problem and what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Package manager to get the new version nuget package. Here is the console code for you to get the latest version: `NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK -Version 1.2.230313.1`.

Here is the [Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK/) Nuget package website you can refer to. In addition, you can update other nuget packages by using the Package manager command.

Comment: I tried this out before posting of course, but Nuget were not updated to higher version.
I took a closer look this morning when I tried to install Nuget Xamarin.Android.Glide 4.14.2.1 via PM and received the following message:

NuGet\Install-Package : NU1202: Package Xamarin.Android.Glide 4.14.2.1 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,version=v7.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Glide 4.14.2.1 supports. 
The following:
  - monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,version=v12.0)
  - net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,version=v6.0)

Comment: Then I looked at all the Xamarin Nuget packages and saw that they support net6.0-android31.0.
I then created a new project to see if these Xamarin packages come in automatically and they do. To be on the safe side, I also created a project on another computer and that is also the case there.

Comment: I suspect that these Xamarin nuggets are preventing the other particular nuggets from being updated to higher versions. It's just strange that I can't find anything about it on the internet. At least with the WebView2 component, someone should have reported this, because it has already had massive problems and had to be updated 2 times in the last 6 months in MAUI Blazer projects.

Comment: That is weird. I prefer you to report it as an issue. because this is not easy to rebuild as a project and it sounds like the nuget package manage problem.